# Apache open others ports

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp, oracle-call-interface

I have an apache web server in XAMPP with PHP and OCI8 for Oracle installed.

My default port for requests is 1934, but Apache automatically opens other ports and sometimes I have to restart to have it run correctly.

In the error log, the only thing that appears is this:

```
[pid 1044:tid256] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d c:/xampp/apache'
[pid 4856:tid258] AH00418: Parent: created child process 4856
[pid 4856:tid258] AH01916: Init: (www.example.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[pid 4856:tid258] AH00354: CHild: starting 150 worker threads
```

[image: Apache Server]

The server software is XAMPP 3.2.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal, because Apache opens a new port for every incoming request and closes it after the request has been handled, so you don't have to worry.

Comment: Thx @tim-speckhals but i start the service and the first connection open multiples port automatically and sometimes dont work until you restart the service

Comment: @LuisTalavera do the open ports affect your RAM and/or CPU (badly)?